# Traefik/Docker: Using ports as a frontend rule (rather than paths or subdomains)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm using docker-compose to setup Traefik as a reverse proxy for a couple services running in Docker containers. I've got it working, but what I'd like to do & am unsure how, is configure it so that each backend is accessed via a different frontend https *port* (rather than a different subdomain or path prefix).

Here's my docker-compose file for Traefik & the first service:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.6-alpine
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - --logLevel=INFO
      - --defaultentrypoints=http,https
      - --entryPoints=Name:http Address::5099 Redirect.EntryPoint:https
      - --entryPoints=Name:https Address::5098 TLS:/cert/certificate.crt,/cert/private.key
      - --docker
      - --docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --docker.domain=example.com
    ports:
      - target: 5099
        published: 5099
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 5098
        published: 5098
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - ./cert:/cert
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always

  firefox-syncserver:
    image: crazymax/firefox-syncserver:latest
    container_name: traefik-firefoxsync
    volumes:
      - ./firefoxsync:/data
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.backend=firefox-syncserver
      - traefik.port=5000
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com
    environment:
      - <...config for firefoxsync...>
    restart: always
```

With this, I can access the service via https://example.com:5098, & all is good. Now let's try to add a second service:

```
  traefik-manictime:
    image: manictime/manictimeserver:latest
    container_name: traefik-manictime
    volumes:
      - ./manictime:/app/Data
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.backend=manictime
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/manictime
    restart: always
```

This is accessible via https://example.com:5098/manictime. However, the problem is that the service itself cannot run in a virtual dir (aka it needs to be in the top level of its domain - no /manictime subdir). While I know I could use subdomains rather than path prefixes to differentiate the services, I would much prefer to use ports instead (one reason among several is that I'm hosting this on a NAS at home, which is not a static IP, so I’m using DDNS to keep the top-level domain pointed in the right place; it's a hassle to have to do this for each & every subdomain).

So the question is: can I somehow configure Traefik so that i.e.

https://example.com:5098 -> https frontend to service 1

https://example.com:6000 -> https frontend to service 2

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new TLS entrypoint on the new port, and either add the new entrypoint to the default list (if you want all TLS services available on the new port), or manually add the new entrypoint to service 2 using the `traefik.frontend.entryPoints` label.

Comment: Perfect! That got me going in the right direction, thanks :)

Comment: @Daniel Tomcej How to in traefik@2.2 please!